# XAMPP - Configure to connect to MySQL without a password

Tags: php, xampp

I'm getting this error any time I access a .php file:

`Connection failed, the reason: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I've seen this error before, but my problem is that `root` has access to the database, but has no password set, as I can use phpmyadmin and can see this: ("No" is for the password column)

[image]

If I run `mysql -u root` I have access to the database as expected, but running `mysql -u root -p` gives me the same error as above.

Some settings from `config.inc.php` are:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Which I think should say use `root` as the user and don't try to use a password.

How do I configure Apache/PHP to not try to use a password when connecting to the database?

Comment: Set password to `null`, but it is something quite opposite to the best practice.

Comment: Tried that with the same error. I noticed if I change user in `config.inc.php` to something other than `root` the error is still for `'root'@'localhost'`. Any ideas where else it could be getting this information?

Comment: Who is 'it'? All you've posted is how you assign values to a config of **something**, which apparently doesn't use this config at all =)